# How to display scanimage progress percentage in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ubuntu

I'm using `exec("scanimage -p ")` to scan file in PHP.

The progress percentage message can be print in command line window, but can it be displayed in web browser with PHP?

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to use WebSocket in order to provide real time data to your client. you can read more here http://socketo.me/